# How to Get specific embedded array from mongodb and append it with new document using mongodb c# driver

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

I want to get specific embedded array from mongodb document and add new document in that embedded array using "mongodb.Driver" .net driver.

am inserting doc as:

```
{
  "_id": "5c41b5c6b0ce0437dc576c53",
  "ProjectId": "234",
  "OwnerId": "62",
  "ProjectName": "proj4h46m",
  "FileDetails": [
    {
      "TotalWord": "-1",
      "RepeatedWord": "-1",
      "TMWordCount": "-1",
      "TranslationRequired": "-1",
      "ParentFileName": "test",
      "ChildFileName": "test_AR-SA",
      "Status": "Newly Uploaded"
    }
  ]
}
```

I expect to get "FileDetails" array from it and add new doc and update to mongodb. as shown below:

```
{
  "_id": "5c41b5c6b0ce0437dc576c53",
  "ProjectId": "234",
  "OwnerId": "62",
  "ProjectName": "proj4h46m",
  "FileDetails": [
    {
      "TotalWord": "-1",
      "RepeatedWord": "-1",
      "TMWordCount": "-1",
      "TranslationRequired": "-1",
      "ParentFileName": "test",
      "ChildFileName": "test_AR-SA",
      "Status": "Newly Uploaded"
    },
    {
      "TotalWord": "10",
      "RepeatedWord": "3",
      "TMWordCount": "12",
      "TranslationRequired": "1",
      "ParentFileName": "test2",
      "ChildFileName": "test_AR-KSA",
      "Status": "Newly Uploaded"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you have and explain why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this by using below method:-

```
 var query2 = Query.EQ(""ProjectId", "234");
 var document=@"{""TotalWord"": ""10"",""RepeatedWord"": "3",""TMWordCount"": ""12"",""TranslationRequired"": ""1"",""ParentFileName"": ""test2"",""ChildFileName"": ""test_AR-KSA"",""Status"": ""Newly Uploaded""}";
 var update = Update.Push("FileDetails", document.ToBsonDocument());
 collec.Update(query2, update);
```